# app crashes due to auto adjusting scrollView?

Tags: ios

I am having a screen for adding a reminder. The screen is having 2 textfields and 1 textview. These all are under scrollView which is a subclass of TPAvoidingScrollView class. This class itself manages the position of scrollView and hence the components inside as the keyboard appears and disappears.

The screen is as follows.

[image]

After I have gone through all the fields and selected certain values. By clicking on Add reminder the event is added into the main calendar and the screen pops out to the previous screen. And then problem  starts to occur. As soon as I again comes to this screen and tapping on the Textview Notes the app crashes with these errors.

[image][image]

Here Reminder view controller is the name of the class
The code for the whole class is:

```
            #import "ReminderViewController.h"
    #import <EventKit/EventKit.h>
    #import "ActionSheetPicker.h"
    #import "NSDate-Utilities.h"

   @interface ReminderViewController ()

    @end

         @implementation ReminderViewController
        @synthesize scrollView;
        @synthesize  txt_notes;
      @synthesize txt_remindOn;
       @synthesize txt_repeatAlarm;
       @synthesize btn_appointment;
       @synthesize btn_pickup;
       @synthesize btn_reminder;
       @synthesize txt_currentFocussedTextField;
        @synthesize selectedDate;
        @synthesize arr_repeatAlarm;
       @synthesize selectedIndex;
       @synthesize isSelected;
        @synthesize str_eventTitle;

     -      (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
       { 
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
     if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    }
     return self;
  }

  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 520);
self.selectedDate = [NSDate date];
self.arr_repeatAlarm = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"None",@"Every Day", @"Every Week", 
   @"Every Month", @"Every year", nil];
btn_reminder.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255 green:89.0/255 blue:178.0/255
  alpha:1.0f];
[[AppDelegate sharedInstance] setUpHighlightedStateOfButton:btn_reminder];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  }


   #pragma mark - Check button click methods

  -(IBAction)btn_appointment_click:(id)sender{
if(btn_appointment.selected){

    [btn_appointment setSelected:NO];
    [btn_pickup setSelected:YES];
    isSelected = NO;
}
else{

    [btn_appointment setSelected:YES];
    [btn_pickup setSelected:NO];
    isSelected = YES;

  }
 }

  -(IBAction)btn_pickup_click:(id)sender{
if(btn_pickup.selected){

    [btn_pickup setSelected:NO];
    [btn_appointment setSelected:YES];
    isSelected = NO;
}
else{

    [btn_pickup setSelected:YES];
    [btn_appointment setSelected:NO];
    isSelected = YES;

   }
  }



     #pragma mark - calendar Event methods
    - (IBAction)btn_reminder_click:(id)sender{

    [self addEventTocalendar:sender];
  }

     - (void)addEventTocalendar:(id)sender{
EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
[store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError
  *error) {
    if (!granted) { return; }
    EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
    event.title  = @"Pickup Reminder";


    event.startDate = self.selectedDate;
    event.endDate = [event.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60];//set 1 hour meeting
    event.notes = txt_notes.text;
    event.recurrenceRules = EKRecurrenceFrequencyDaily;
    [event addAlarm:[EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:60.0f * -5.0f]];
    if (selectedIndex == 1) {
        [event addRecurrenceRule:[[EKRecurrenceRule 
  alloc]initRecurrenceWithFrequency:EKRecurrenceFrequencyDaily interval:1 end:Nil]];

    }
    else if (selectedIndex == 2){
        [event addRecurrenceRule:[[EKRecurrenceRule 
     alloc]initRecurrenceWithFrequency:EKRecurrenceFrequencyWeekly interval:1 end:Nil]];
    }
    else if (selectedIndex == 3){
        [event addRecurrenceRule:[[EKRecurrenceRule 
     alloc]initRecurrenceWithFrequency:EKRecurrenceFrequencyMonthly interval:1 end:Nil]];
    }
    else if (selectedIndex == 4){
        [event addRecurrenceRule:[[EKRecurrenceRule 
    alloc]initRecurrenceWithFrequency:EKRecurrenceFrequencyYearly interval:1 end:Nil]];
    }
    [event setCalendar:[store defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
    NSError *err = nil;
    [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];
    NSString *savedEventId = event.eventIdentifier;  //this is so you can access this 
    event later
    BOOL isSuceess=[store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
    // This needs to be done as the UIKIT was getting called from the seconadary thread 
    and therefore to show the alert view in the main thread and to prevent the hanging of
      the app I have to call the Aletview method in the main thread.
    // i.e dispatch the event in the main thread

    if(isSuceess){
        UIAlertView *alertview = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Event" 
       message:@"Event added in calendar" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
       otherButtonTitles:nil];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [alertview show];

        });
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alertview = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Event" message:[err
       description] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [alertview show];
        });
    }
}];

}
   - (void)back{
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
   #pragma mark - UIAlertViewDelegate methods
 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  }

    #pragma mark - Implementation methods

 - (void)serviceWasSelected:(NSNumber *)selectedIndex element:(id)element {

self.selectedIndex = [selectedIndex intValue];
//may have originated from textField or barButtonItem, use an IBOutlet instead of element
self.txt_repeatAlarm.text = [self.arr_repeatAlarm objectAtIndex:self.selectedIndex];
      }

 - (void)dateWasSelected:(NSDate *)selectedDate element:(id)element{ //indexpath:
  (NSIndexPath *)indexpath{
UITextField  * textfield = (UITextField *)element;
if (textfield == self.txt_remindOn) {


      self.selectedDate = selectedDate;
      self.txt_remindOn.text = [self.selectedDate getDateStringInFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy
     hh:mm aa"];
   }

 }


   #pragma mark - TextField Delegate Methods
  - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
self.txt_currentFocussedTextField = textField;

[[AppDelegate sharedInstance] addToolbarForKeyboard:textField];



if (textField == self.txt_remindOn) {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    _actionSheetPicker = [[ActionSheetDatePicker alloc] initWithTitle:@"" 

        datePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime selectedDate:self.selectedDate
        minimumDate:[NSDate
date] maximumDate:Nil target:self action:@selector(dateWasSelected:element:)
      origin:textField];
    self.actionSheetPicker.hideCancel = NO;
    [self.actionSheetPicker showActionSheetPicker];

}

if (textField == self.txt_repeatAlarm) {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [ActionSheetStringPicker showPickerWithTitle:@"" rows:self.arr_repeatAlarm 
    initialSelection:self.selectedIndex target:self 
   successAction:@selector(serviceWasSelected:element:) 
  cancelAction:@selector(actionPickerCancelled:) origin:textField];
}

}




// making the keyboard disappear on pressing the Done button on the keyboard.
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return NO;
}

  - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range
   replacementText:(NSString *)text {

    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
  }

   return YES;
  }






   - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
   {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

  @end
```

Comment: According to the log, the app crashes when calling `respondsToSelector` on RemidnerViewController. Please post the code where this method is called.

Comment: I am not able to find that from where my class is calling this method?